# How can I print scroll tab content with whole page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

As shown in an image I want to print the whole page with scroll content of tab. Currently the only visible screen content is being printed

Answer (score 0):

You may use CSS media selectors to alter your styling for components when printing:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

It is perhaps the cleanest solution as it was meant for such situations. Ofc, it may require to address CSS for all the components on the page to make the outcome look as desired.